Sorting a DataFrame by Multiple Conditions in Pandas
I'm struggling with a specific sort that I'm not managing to implement in Python.
Here's a sample dataframe
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'product': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'quantity': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
    'cost': [0, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I'd like the dataframe to be sorted by cost ASC "whenever possible", but the quantity should be ordered strictly ASC per product.
So the output would be.



product
quantity
cost




A
0
0


B
0
2


B
1
4


B
2
4


A
1
5


A
2
3



Here, we see that the cost is not ordered ASC strictly (cf line 5).
But it's the only way to order the dataset, respecting the quantity order within product.
I've tried several ways, this one works, as it picks items one by one. But it's pretty time consuming!

def sortDataframe(df):
    
    df['index'] = df.sort_values(by='quantity', ascending=True).groupby('product').cumcount()
    df['lastIndex'] = 0
    df['sortOrder'] = None
    
    # Pour chaque ligne
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        # On identifie la ligne avec la cout le plus faible, parmi les index de recherche
        idx = df[df['index']==df['lastIndex']]['cost'].idxmin()
        # On défini son nouvel ordre
        df.at[idx, 'sortOrder'] = i
        # On incrémente le prochain index de recherche pour le produit concerne
        df.loc[df['product']==df.at[idx, 'product'], 'lastIndex'] = df.at[idx, 'lastIndex']+1
    
    # On applique le tri
    df = df.sort_values(by=['sortOrder'])
    
    # On supprime les colonnes temporaires
    del df['lastIndex']
    del df['sortOrder']
    del df['index']

    return df

result = sortDataframe(df)
print(result)



Shouldn't the values be sorted A 0 B 0 A 1 B 1 A 2 B 2 or A 0 A 1 A 2 B 0 B 1 B 2?

Thx for your assistance Guy.
Unfortunately, your proposed sorts are correct.
They both respect the quantity order by product. And for sure are easy to produce.
But...
Case 1 / A 0 B 0 A 1 B 1 A 2 B 2 => does not respect the increasing costs, so B 1 (with cost of 4) should come before A 1 (with cost of 5)
Case 2 / A 0 A 1 A 2 B 0 B 1 B 2 => same reason
This sorting is pretty tricky to obtain.
